# How to fill Object Array and find minimum value for the Object Array

Tags: java, object, arraylist, constructor, text-files

**EDIT SOLUTION**

Based on forpas code, I move thing around little bit, and now the minimum value displays as expected. Thank you guys for all your help.

```
public static StudentGrade findMinIndex(StudentGrade[] studentGrades) 
{       
    StudentGrade studentGradeMin = studentGrades[0];

    for(int i=0; i < studentGrades.length; i++) 
    {
        if(studentGradeMin.getGrade()[0] > studentGrades[i].getGrade()[i]) 
        {
            studentGradeMin.getGrade()[0] = studentGrades[i].getGrade()[i];

        }                  
    }

    System.out.println(studentGradeMin.getGrade()[0]);

    return studentGradeMin;

}
```

EDIT:

Now that I can print out the number, I have problem with finding minimum value. I keep getting error message: 
"The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) StudentGrade, StudentGrade"

I need to find minimum value for my object array, but I can't print the object correctly. The result will not display like integers.
Can someone help me please?

This is my text file

6
John 97.5
Jim 99
Kathy 34
Steve 86.5
Stacy 43
Faith 88

This is my methods

//This is the constructor class

```
public class StudentGrade
{   

      private String[] names;
      private double[] grades; // instance variable


      // constructor initializes grades with parameter grades               
      public StudentGrade(double[] grades, String[] names) 
      {                                                                 
         this.grades = grades; 
         this.names = names;
      }                                                                
      // method to set the grades
      public void setGrade(double[] grades)
      {
         this.grades = grades;
      }

      // method to retrieve the grades
      public double[] getGrade()
      {
         return grades;
      }


      //Set name
      public void setName(String[] names)
      {
         this.names = names;
      }

      // method to retrieve the names
      public String[] getName()
      {
         return names;
      }
}
```

//This is my main class

```
   public static StudentGrade[] initialize(String inputFileName)   throws FileNotFoundException 
    {           
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("grade.txt"));   

    int size = scan.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[size];
    double[] grades = new double[size];
    int index = 0;
    String[] col = null;

    while(scan.hasNextLine())           
    {
        names[index] = scan.next();
        grades[index] = scan.nextDouble();
        index++;

    }

    StudentGrade[] studentGrades = new StudentGrade[grades.lenght];
    for(int i=0; i< studentGrades; i++)
    {
       studentGrades[i] = new StudentGrade(grades, names);

    }

    for(int i=0; i< grades.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(studentGrades[i].getGrade());
    }

    scan.close();
    return studentGrades;
  }

 //This is to find minimum value

public static StudentGrade findMinIndex(StudentGrade[] studentGrades) 
{

    StudentGrade studentGradeMax = studentGrades[0];

     for(int i=1;i<studentGrades.length;i++)
     {
        if(studentGrades[i] > studentGradeMax) ==> Error "The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) StudentGrade, StudentGrade"
        {
            studentGradeMax = studentGrades[i];
        }
      }
      return studentGradeMax;


}

The code return these values instead of real number
[D@3d4eac69
[D@3d4eac69
[D@3d4eac69
[D@3d4eac69
```

[D@3d4eac69
[D@3d4eac69

Comment: How do you define minimum, it is not clear from your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing by:

```
System.out.println(studentGrades[i].getGrade());
```

but `getGrade()` returns an array, so change to this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studentGrades[i].getGrade()));
```

or if the array contains only 1 number:

```
System.out.println(studentGrades[i].getGrade()[0]);
```

**Edit**

```
public static StudentGrade findMinGrade(StudentGrade[] studentGrades) {
    StudentGrade studentGradeMin = studentGrades[0];
    for(int i=1; i < studentGrades.length; i++) {
        if(studentGrades[i].getGrade()[0] < studentGradeMin.getGrade()[0]) {
            studentGradeMin = studentGrades[i];
        }
    }
    return studentGradeMin;
}
```

Check it, I hope there are no typos.  
This returns the `StudentGrade` object inside the array `studentGrades` with the min grade.

Comment: @ forpas - Thanks. I'm new to this, not sure what it means but wonder I can't accept 2 answers? both are good.

Comment: @Thi no you can accept only 1 answer. When you get rep at least 15 you can upvote answers as well that you think are useful.

Comment: Do you know how can I find minimum value for Object array? I can do it with double type array, but don't know how to work with Object array type?

Comment: If you mean minimum index it's always 0. If you mean something else give an example.

Comment: this is my object array: John 97.5 Jim 99 Kathy 34 Steve 86.5 Stacy 43 Faith 88 -- I need to display the smallest number using the findMinIndex(StudentGrade[] studentGrades)  method I have above.

Comment: Give me a few mins to check

Comment: the smallest value here is 34.

Comment: that's where my headache is. The method must be "StudentGrade findMinGrade" not double. That's why I can't return a double, and don't know how to return with StudentGrade class :((

Comment: Ok then I will repost

Comment: cool it doesn't throw error any more but the result come out as:
John, Jim, Kathy, Steve, Stacy, Faith, 97.5, 99.0, 34.0, 86.5, 43.0, 88.0

Comment: Why? What does `StudentGrade` store? All the names and all the grades? If so then why do you create an array of `StudentGrade`?

Comment: that array store both name and grade, but if we call getGrade, then we will only get grade. I print it out the way you show me, this time I move the print inside for loop, and get the whole row instead of 1 number
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studentGradeMin.getGrade()));

[97.5, 99.0, 34.0, 86.5, 43.0, 88.0]

Comment: The code in my original answer showed you how to print an array. Now your next issue is that you want a min value from an array and this is what the code in my edit does. **But** it looks like you pass an array to another array. Maybe all the design you made is wrong. Why do you need this array `StudentGrade[]` when `StudentGrade` itself stores an array of names and an array of grades. This is array inside an array.

Comment: that's my hw assignment. If I can just use StudentGrade object itself, then it would be less work. Not sure why we have to create a StudentGrade class, then create an object array for it, and have to use it for all that calculation. With your method, I can get a numbers out, just the whole array of number, not one smallest one. Not sure because the way I print it out not correct?
I also try to print this way:
System.out.println(studentGradeMin.getGrade()[i]);

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results and the use of the array `StudentGrade[]` instead of `StudentGrade` which stores all the needed info does not make sense.

Comment: if you copy the entire code, and replace with your findMinIndex, then you will be able to see I hope. I have 1 initialize method, 1 findMinIndex, 1 constructor class, and a text file. I just use main method to call the print out to validate. The text file is also in my post. 
By the way, thank you very much for taking your time to look into this for me. I really appreciated.

Comment: I did copy your code and it's not possible to write a method for the minimum grade that returns a `StudentGrade` object, since a `StudentGrade` object contains all the grades of all the students. Look at the `StudentGrade` class. It has 2 arrays, 1 for all the names and 1 for all the grades. So every `StudentGrade` object contains all that information and not just 1 grade.

Comment: OMG, I don't know what I did, I moved some of your code around, and now it works. Let me post the solution. Thank you very much for this, I have been staying up all night, pulling my hair out ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to override the String toString() method from the Object class since that is the default method used when printing an object

So in your StudentGrade method you would add

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return //your fields
}
```

The problem here is that your member fields in StudentGrade are arrays which is a little strange so I guess your toString would look like this for example

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (String name : names) {
        out.append(name);
        out.append(", ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length - 1; i++) {
        out.append(grades[i]);
        out.append(", ");
    }
    out.append(grades[grades.length - 1]);

    return out.toString();
}
```